# Twilio Verify API verification call return curl error

Tags: twilio-api

I am now trying out the Twilio Verify API and the guides actually showed there are only two calls to the API to send the OTP to the target phone number and check if the OTP entered by end user is correct or not. I have problem with the verify code part, which return the curl error.

The OTP is successfully sent to the target phone.

This is the curl command i used to check the OTP:

```
curl -GET 'https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/check' -d api_key=xxxx -d verification_code=xxxx-d phone_number=xx-d country_code=xx
```

This is the error message:

```
curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not reading the error message properly, I fixed it already by add the SSL cert path and private key path of the server to the curl command and it works.

```
curl -GET 'https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/check' -d api_key=xxxx -d verification_code=xxxx-d phone_number=xx-d country_code=xx --cert path/to/fullchain.pem --key path/to/privkey.pem
```